# Quarkus @ConfigMapping: when no prefix defined, skip/ignore system and environment variables, only scan properties with defined keys

Tags: quarkus

Some properties defined in my app are used by other applications in the same organization, so I cannot add a dedicated namespace before them to differentiate. While moving to Quarkus `@ConfigMapping`, I found Quarkus by default scans all system and environment variables as well as application scoped properties, and non-mapped properties will stop app from launching, showing a lot of "cannot find any root to map" error.

Answer (score 2):

Quarkus YAML config is based on Smallrye config, which has:

```
smallrye.config.mapping.validate-unknown=false
```

to stop this behaviour.

https://smallrye.io/smallrye-config/2.11.1/config/mappings/#retrieval

> For a Config Mapping to be valid, it needs to match every configuration property name contained in the Config under the specified prefix set in @ConfigMapping. This prevents unknown configuration properties in the Config. This behaviour can be disabled with the configuration `smallrye.config.mapping.validate-unknown=false`.